# Nodejs : ReferenceError: express is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, server

I begin to use Nodejs to create web servers, and for this, I use express module. Then, I intalled it with command : "sudo npm install -g express".
But after lanched the program, this error occured :

> "ReferenceError: express is not defined
>       at Object. (/home/louis/Documents/Programming/Web/Nodejs/Test/server.js:1:85)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:608:3 "

I decided to install it localy but in vain...

Here is the code I use :

```
let express = require(express);
let app = express();

console.log("Hello world !");

app.listen(80);
```

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic. Typo. `require(express)` should be `require("express")`. The [hello world example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) is clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Express needs to be in quotes

```
let express = require('express')
```

**Off-Topic:**

You probably don't want that variable to be modified in the future, so you probably want to force it to stay that way. Most time you want required variables to be `constant` which is a common practice:

```
const express = require('express')
```

Comment: * `const express = require('express')`